# Unable to render map loop return in Ionic React

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-react

I have a ionSelect in my application with which I am trying to show selected test on event "onIonChnage" in the table as table row. the state gets updated but the map loop do not return/display the table row as expected. I have searched on the web but could not find any solution. Any help will highly be appriciated! I am sharing the code as well:

```
    import {
    IonBackButton,
    IonButton, IonButtons,
    IonContent, IonDatetime,
    IonHeader, IonIcon, IonImg,
    IonInput,
    IonItem,
    IonLabel,
    IonList,
    IonPage, IonSelect, IonSelectOption,
    IonTitle,
    IonToolbar,
    IonGrid, IonRow, IonCol,
} from '@ionic/react';

import './BookApointment.scss';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {arrowBackOutline, chevronDownOutline, closeCircleOutline} from "ionicons/icons";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import axios from "axios";
import { BASE_URL, URL } from "../BaseUrll";

const cookies = new Cookies();

const BookAppointment: React.FC = () => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState<string>();
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState<string>();
    const [guardianName, setGuardianName] = useState<string>();
    const [gender, setGender] = useState<string>('Male');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>();
    const [address, setAddress] = useState<string>();
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState<string>();
    const [user, setUser] = useState<any>({});
    const [maritalStatus, setMaritalStatus] = useState<any>('Married');
    const [collectionCenter, setCollectionCenter] = useState<any>('1');
    const [collectionCenters, setCollectionCenters] = useState<any>([]);
    const [availableTests, setAvailableTests] = useState<any>([]);
    const [selectedTests, setSelectedTests] = useState<any>([]);
    const [tests, setTests] = useState<any>('1');
    const [count, setCount] = useState<any>(null);

    const options = {
        cssClass: 'select-dropdown'
    };

    useEffect(() =>{
        
        let url = URL + "/collection-center";
        axios
        .get(url, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${cookies.get('access_token_lims')}` },
        })
        .then((res) => {
            setCollectionCenters(res.data.data);
            if(res.data.data.length > 0){
                setCollectionCenter(res.data.data[0].id);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });

        url = URL + "/test";
        axios
        .get(url, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${cookies.get('access_token_lims')}` },
        })
        .then((res) => {
            setAvailableTests(res.data.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },[]);

    const test_selection = async (e:any) =>{
        if(e.detail.value != 'choose'){
            var userSelectedTests = selectedTests;
            
            if(!userSelectedTests.includes(e.detail.value)){
                userSelectedTests.push(parseInt(e.detail.value));
                setSelectedTests(userSelectedTests);
            }
        }
    }

    const removeTestFromSelection = async (idx:any) =>{
        var userSelectedTests = selectedTests;
        const index = userSelectedTests.indexOf(idx);
        userSelectedTests.splice(index, 1);
        
        await setSelectedTests(userSelectedTests);
    }

    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonHeader className="header-center">
                <IonToolbar color="primary">
                    <IonButtons slot="start">
                        <IonBackButton text="" icon={arrowBackOutline} defaultHref=""/>
                    </IonButtons>
                    <IonTitle>Book an Appointment</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
            <IonContent fullscreen className="ion-padding">
                <div className="booking-container">

                    <div className="booking-info">
                        <IonList lines="none">

                            <IonItem className="custom-input">
                                <IonInput value={firstName} type="text" placeholder="First Name"
                                          onIonChange={(e)=>{}} clearInput></IonInput>
                            </IonItem>

                            <IonItem className="custom-input">
                                <IonInput value={lastName} type="text" placeholder="Last Name"
                                          onIonChange={(e)=>{}} clearInput></IonInput>
                            </IonItem>

                            <IonItem className="custom-input">
                                <IonInput value={guardianName} type="text" placeholder="Guardian Name"
                                          onIonChange={(e)=>{}} clearInput></IonInput>
                            </IonItem>

                            <div className="select-list">
                                <IonIcon icon={chevronDownOutline}/>
                                <IonSelect value={gender} interface="action-sheet" interfaceOptions={options}
                                           onIonChange={(e) =>{}}>
                                    <IonSelectOption value="Male">Male</IonSelectOption>
                                    <IonSelectOption value="Female">Female</IonSelectOption>
                                </IonSelect>
                            </div>

                            <IonItem className="custom-input">
                                <IonInput value={email} type="email" placeholder="Email"
                                          onIonChange={(e)=>{}} clearInput></IonInput>
                            </IonItem>

                            <IonItem className="custom-input">
                                <IonInput value={phoneNumber} placeholder="Phone Number"
                                          onIonChange={(e)=>{}} clearInput></IonInput>
                            </IonItem>

                            <IonItem className="custom-input">
                                <IonDatetime className="ion-text-right" placeholder="DD MMMM YYYY" displayFormat="DD MMMM YYYY" onIonChange={(e) => {}}></IonDatetime>
                            </IonItem>

                            <IonItem className="custom-input">
                                <IonInput value={address} type="text" placeholder="Guardian Name"
                                          onIonChange={(e)=>{}} clearInput></IonInput>
                            </IonItem>

                            <div className="select-list">
                                <IonIcon icon={chevronDownOutline}/>
                                <IonSelect value={maritalStatus} interface="action-sheet" interfaceOptions={options}
                                           onIonChange={(e)=>{}}>
                                    <IonSelectOption value="Married">Married</IonSelectOption>
                                    <IonSelectOption value="Unmarried">Unmarried</IonSelectOption>
                                </IonSelect>
                            </div>

                            <div className="select-list">
                                <IonIcon icon={chevronDownOutline}/>
                                <IonSelect value={collectionCenter} interface="action-sheet" interfaceOptions={options}
                                           onIonChange={(e)=>{}}>
                                    {collectionCenters.map((item:any, index:any)=>{
                                        return(
                                            <IonSelectOption key={index} value={item.id}>{item.name}</IonSelectOption>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </IonSelect>
                            </div>

                            <div className="select-list">
                                <IonIcon icon={chevronDownOutline}/>
                                <IonSelect value={'choose'} interface="action-sheet" interfaceOptions={options}
                                           onIonChange={(e)=>{test_selection(e)}}>
                                    <IonSelectOption value='choose'>Choose a Test</IonSelectOption>
                                    {availableTests.map((item:any, index:any) =>{
                                        return(
                                            <IonSelectOption key={index} value={index}>{item.name}</IonSelectOption>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </IonSelect>
                            </div>
                        </IonList>

                        <div className="test-table-wrapper">
                            <table className="test-table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Test Name</th>
                                        <th>Amount</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {selectedTests.map((item:number, index:any) =>{
                                            console.log(selectedTests);
                                            <tr key={index}>
                                                <td>{availableTests[item].name}</td>
                                                <td>{availableTests[item].amount}</td>
                                                <td><IonIcon onClick={() =>{removeTestFromSelection(index);}} icon={closeCircleOutline}/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        })}
                                    </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <IonButton expand="block" className="custom-btn">Book Appointment</IonButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    );
};

export default BookAppointment;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should `return` your code explicitly when you use `{}` with map.

add missing `return` keyword.

```
<tbody>
    {selectedTests.map((item: number, index: any) => {
      console.log(selectedTests);
      return (<tr key={index}>
        <td>{availableTests[item].name}</td>
        <td>{availableTests[item].amount}</td>
        <td>
          <IonIcon
            onClick={() => {
              removeTestFromSelection(index);
            }}
            icon={closeCircleOutline}
          />
        </td>
      </tr>)
    })}
  </tbody>
```